# How to update multiple records of the column in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server

I want to update a column in a table, by increment its value by 1.
Here I attach the code I tried

```
declare @count int 
, @num int
, @Seed VARCHAR(10) = 'PR0001'
, @IncrementedValue int = 0
, @Code varchar(10)

set @count = (select Count(*) from psa.ProductDemo)
while @num <= @count
begin

    update psa.ProductDemo 
    set Code='PR' + right('0000' + cast(@IncrementedValue as varchar(10)),4) 
    where Code != null

    set @IncrementedValue = @IncrementedValue + 1

    set @num = @num + 1 

end

select * 
from psa.ProductDemo
```

output

1-)

```
457B995D-CF6E-4126-A006-A8E45D36A246    PR0002   Toothed Fruit Mill NULL    2018-01-06 00:00:00.000 NULL    8435    NULL    2018-11-02 12:26:20.923 NULL    NULL    NULL
```

2-)

```
B5F46B95-EA8D-4988-9536-45757E371B14    PR0002  Accessories for Disintegrator   NULL    2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    8479    NULL    2018-11-02 12:26:20.923 NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add sample data and expected results?

Comment: What `@Seed VARCHAR(10) = 'PR0001'` for? you did not use it.

Comment: no im not using it

Comment: i want to update that 2nd column PR0002 by increment by 1 for each new record

Comment: Why use a cursor at all? SQL is a set-based language. You can use a *single* UPDATE statement to update multiple records. You can generate incrementing numbers in many ways, eg with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function if you don't care about the actual values or a `SEQUENCE` if you do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use a loop/`CURSOR` here, it'll be awfully slow. A far better approach would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and a CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Code,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {ORDER BY COLUMN}) AS RN
    FROM psa.ProductDemo 
    WHERE Code IS NOT NULL -- != NULL won't work
    )
UPDATE CTE
SET Code = 'PR' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(4),RN),4);
```

Note the section in braces (`{}`), which needs attention from you. Also, note the comment about `code != NULL`. `{expression} (=/!=/>/</etc) NULL` will always return `Unknown` (thus never be true). When comparing `NULL` you always need to use `IS (NOT) NULL`.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @dhanildinesan the error is literally telling you the problem **`the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`** End your statements with a semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 2):

You never initially set `@num`, so it is `NULL`. `NULL + 1 = NULL`, and `NULL <= [somenumber] = UNKNOWN`, so you never actually update anything. The solution would be to set `@num` the same way you do with `@IncrementedValue`.

By the way, you can also do this set based with a `ROW_NUMBER()`. If your code *is* working, you will update the same rows multiple times (ending up with identical codes), because every loop you update `code` for the records `where Code != null` (which should be `IS (NOT?) NULL`).